# I Cannot Place a Window on My Second Monitor Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

It is very odd, but after updating my system from 16.04 to 20.04, the displays do not properly extend. My setup is running an extended display to the left of my built in laptop display.

Under Settings > Displays > JoinDisplay. After making changes to the display the "Keep these changes" window will appear across both of my monitors. After accepting the changes I attempt to drag any window to my rightmost (built in laptop) monitor. However, when any window is dragged to my rightmost monitor, Ubuntu thinks I am trying to extend it on the right half of my leftmost monitor.

Therefore, the rightmost monitor can never be properly used, and any window dragged there ends up on the right side of my left screen.

Any help would be very appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: How did you get from 16.04 to 20.04? What graphics card? What driver? What screens, connected how? What desktop? We'll need a lot more info to go on.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I am new here haha

I used the sudo do-release-upgrade -d command to upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04. This brought me through the command line motions for setup and that was quite quick to work.

I am running a RazorBlade latop with a 2060, and I am currently using the 440 nvidia driver.

The screen is a Samsung C27F398 connected via a WD19 Dell dock though my laptop's USB C port.

Comment: You are still not telling the whole story here. You can't directly skip forward 2 LTS releases, as far as I know. *What* "command line motions"? You are not giving an appropriate level of detail, and as a result, I am having to fish for the info needed to even make suggestions. Please do not do this. Give *ALL* the info you can. Every step, full make and model names, firmware versions, EVERYTHING.